# Comparing 2 string arrays in C

Tags: c

So I'm comparing a string arrays of mixed letters and numbers to a array with the alphabet and then collecting the similar characters (i.e: only the letters) and putting it into a different string array and then printing it.

It works fine the first time around. Although the second time around, if the string being compared to the alphabet is smaller than a certain size it stuffs up and shows some extra letters and sometimes a question mark which comes out of no where.

This is the first time around output:

```
Enter a string (1-40 characters): zxcvbnm,./asdfghjkl;qwertyuiop[]
Output: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

and then the second time around:

```
Enter a string (1-40 characters): abcdefg
Output: abcdefgz?
```

See what I mean? 'z?' popped up out of nowhere.

Could it be that theres some left over letters in the buffer or anything once the function is called again?

```
It turns out that I didn't have a null terminator at the end of the newest 
string before being printed! - Thanks to Mohamed!
```

Comment: please provide the code. probably you have a terminator null  charachter missing

Comment: there is a risk to close your question if you do not provide your code

Comment: Sorry one sec, i'm quite new to StackOverFlow. I'm pretty sure the other answers are correct with the null terminator, but none the less i'm seeing where exactly to provide the code.

Comment: Post it in the question, and use proper indentation.

Comment: Done. I always indent properly. :)

Comment: `sprintf(prompt, "Enter a string (1-40): ", INPUT_LENGTH);` is not doing any formatting, there's no `%` in the format string.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have a null terminator. Thanks guys!
Is there a problem in taking down my code but adding the solution? Only as it's a question in an assignment of mine. I wrote that myself and don't want someone else in my course to stumble upon it. Haha.

Comment: Mixing tabs and spaces is not proper indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code, your string should finish with null character `'\0'`. This is the cause of your problem.

in your code you have to add

```
letters[z]= '\0';
```

after the `for`

```
    for (x = 0; x < 26; x++){
        for (y = 0; y < strLen1; y++){
            if (alphabet[x] == string[y])
            {
                letters[z]=string[y];
                /* Increment z, to insert anothe letter in an empty space. */
                z++;
            }
        }
    }
    letters[z]= '\0'; // add this line
    printf("Output: %s\n\n", letters);
```

BTW you can optimize your check of alphabet

Lower case alphabets {a, b, c, ......,z} are refenced with their ASCII.

so you can check that the ASCII of the `string[y]` is between the ASCII of `'a'` and the ASCII of `'z'` instead of looking into the `alphabet[]` array. It's more simple

Comment: That's it! How stupid of me! Thank you very much good sir! :)

Comment: Do you mean something like "if (string[y] >= 'a' && string[y] <= 'z'??

Comment: yes exactelly that's wat I mean

Comment: SO much easier. Again, got no idea why that didn't pop into my head.
Thanks again Mohamed.

Answer (score 3):

Strings in C are NUL-terminated You need to terminate your character array before printing it.

Set the character after the last to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [`isalpha()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) to check if a `char` is an alphebetical character. No need to re-invent, and then there's also no need to convert to lower case manually since it handles either.

Comment: Wow. Honestly i'm never heard of is isalpha() before. How does it work exactly?

Comment: @PhantomThief1412 There are several isXXX functions. Look it up in any online C manual. My google karma got this hit: http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha